# Infinite UITableView Scroll with NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm trying to use [this](http://iphone2020.wordpress.com/2012/10/01/uitableview-tricks-part-2-infinite-scrolling/) method to implement an infinitely scrolling `UITableView`

The core logic of the solution is:

1. To increase the tableview content by a factor of 3, so that we make the 3 copies of the content laid one after another vertically.
2. Whenever the top end of the scroll is reached, move the the scroll offset back to start of the 2nd copy
3. When the bottom end of the scroll is reached, we move the scroll offset back to the start of the 2nd copy minus the height of the tableview, so that we end up showing the same content as we are now.

This means that a single cell insert or delete actually results in three inserts or deletes. Because my table's datasource is populated by an `NSFetchedResultsController` it causes an Assertion Failure.

> The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (12) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (15), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).

Is there some way to stop the program from crashing in these cases? I'd really appreciate any help/pointers. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This can be kind of tricky in iOS especially when you're first starting out. The key is to update the datasource that is backing your `UITableView` before you inform the tableview of changes.

For instance, if you have an `NSArray` backing your tableview, then you will want to remove or add items to it, prior to calling `reloadSection:` on the tableview.

Although it is the least optimized solution, while your testing feel free to simply call `reloadData` which will ignore what the tableview has cached and force it to recalculate based on whatever is backing the tableview.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` method `controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:`. To insert\delete 3 objects.

To keep it simple you could return `3` for number of sections in your table view (this will handle getting 3 copies of objects). And then in your `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` update objects in all sections of your `UITableView` (insert, delete or move). You should use row number from the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` and apply all changes 3 times each for different section. Remember to keep it consistent with `UITableView` data source method `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`.